# Code to update a sql field of a user by clicking in button component sent in email

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, laravel

I need to update a user int field in SQL by clicking button that was sent to my email.

I tried doing this ://127.0.0.1:8000/edit/{id}

I tried connection to email and SQL Server but it didn't work.

My current send controller is:

```
public function store() {

    $data = request()->validate([
        'txt_name' => 'required',
        'num_empleado' => 'required',
        'txt_planta' => 'required',
        'txt_puesto' => 'required',
        'txt_depa' => 'required',
        'area' => 'required',
        'txt_jefe' => 'required',
        'diaSolicitado' => 'required',
        'txt_emailjefe'=>'required'


    ]);

    Mail::to('email.com')->send(new Form($data));
    return redirect('edit-records')->with('message','  your application was successfull');

and my email template is


@component('mail::message') Solicitud día IMI

Por Medio del 
Del empleado: {{$data['txt_name']}}
Numero de empleado: {{$data['num_empleado']}}
Puesto: {{$data['txt_puesto']}}
Planta: {{$data['txt_planta']}}
Departamento: {{$data['txt_depa']}}
Área: {{$data['area']}}
Día Solicitado: {{$data['diaSolicitado']}}
@component('mail::button', ['url' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8000']) autorizacion
@component('mail::button', ['url' => '',]) 

@endcomponent

Thanks
@endcomponent
```

I expect the output to show a success message by confirming in the email the status.

I expect to update the specific field and show a success message:

> Its up

I expect to update specific SQL field and show a success message on a web page.